Flink and HDFS integration via Docker
I have flink jobmanager and taskmanager nodes and also hdfs namenode and datanode working as Docker containers.
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.17.2-scala_2.12-java8
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - HADOOP_CLASSPATH=??
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        ...

  taskmanager:
    image: flink:1.17.2-scala_2.12-java8
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    scale: 2
    environment:
      - HADOOP_CLASSPATH=??
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        ...


  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:latest
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9000:9000
      - 8020:8020
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=hadoop-cluster
      - HDFS_CONF_dfs_blocksize=128m
      - HDFS_CONF_dfs_replication=1

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:latest
    ports:
      - 9864:9864
    depends_on:
      - namenode
    scale: 1
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=hadoop-cluster
      - SERVICE_PRECONDITION=namenode:9870
      - HDFS_CONF_dfs_blocksize=128m
      - HDFS_CONF_dfs_replication=1
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020


To run the job I need to specify HADOOP_CLASSPATH environmental variable in Flink containers.
hadoop classpath inside namenode container takes me this:
# export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
# echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH
/etc/hadoop:/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/yarn:/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/yarn/*

However, I don't understand how to specify HADOOP_CLASSPATH inside the Flink container, given that hadoop itself is installed in another container. Any help will be appreciated.

Flink needs the HADOOP_CLASSPATH so that it can access the JAR files. These JAR files must be locally available to Flink.
AFAIK you can't expose part of one container's filesystem to another, without using a mount in between (to which you'd then need to copy the necessary files on the Hadoop container before they'd be available on the Flink ones).
Another option would be to build your own Flink containers to extend the flink:1.17.2-scala_2.12-java8 images. Here's an example of doing that - in this case I just picked out the JARs that I figured out my Flink program needed, rather than the whole of the Hadoop distribution. You can read more about this approach here (under ‍This is where it gets "fun": Hadoop Dependency heading)

Thanks for your answer. It's gonna be a temporal solution, so I installed the whole Hadoop distribution at ~/hadoop and set HADOOP_CLASSPATH and HADOOP_CONF_DIR. But I still have the initial problem that got me looking for a way to integrate Flink and Hadoop.
Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 'hdfs'.  ... Cannot support file system for 'hdfs' via Hadoop, because Hadoop is not in the classpath, or some classes are missing from the classpath.
Maybe you know how to solve this problem? Maybe those environment variables are not enough?

Where are you installing Hadoop? Where are you setting the environment variables? If it's in Docker you need to make the JARs available to the Flink container.

Hadoop is now installed in flink jobmanager container, and that's where environmental variables defined

how did you do that? did you relaunch Flink process after setting the Environment variable? Please update your question with details.
